# Elementary os i type v but get ü on keyboard

Tags: operating-system, keyboard-layout, elementary-os

Every time I type in my keyboǎrd some wěird chǎractérs appeǎr (example thís text, that took quite a while to compóse)

I just cannot type V except uppercáse. Prompts show thís:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JntU8.png)

Please note I have been úsing thése layouts for years:

- Englísh Int w/dead keys
- Englísh Int w/Alt Gr keys

BTW, this happened after an "intervention" from a bored toddler. I have not found a setting related to thís, so far

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found it. Input method was changed.

Seems asking the question self-shamed me into keep looking